# LDAP: error code 21 - ct;binary: value #0 invalid per syntax

Tags: java, ldap, spring-ldap

I'm trying to add a certificate as a binary attribute value from a byte array, but I'm getting this error.

```
ct;binary: value #0 invalid per syntax
```

If I replace the byte array with the cert base64 string, the same error occurs.

This is my code:

```
attr = new BasicAttribute("ct;binary", CertificateBytes);
item = new ModificationItem(DirContext.ADD_ATTRIBUTE, attr);
ModificationItem[] modifyItems = {item};
ldapTemplate.modifyAttributes(dn, modifyItems);
```

Comment: moved error into body and fixed spelling/grammar

Answer (score 1):

There's a system property setting, `java.naming.ldap.attributes.binary` (more information [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jndi/jndi-ldap-gl.html)), which specifies which attributes should be handled as binary by the Java LDAP provider. You might want to try playing around with that.